# What happens to the second forward slash?

Tags: ios, swift, url-encoding

Why does

```
"http://blah/".stringByAppendingPathComponent("foo")
```

return

```
"http:/blah/foo"
```

Notice the dropped forward slash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the documentation for stringByAppendingPathComponent, you will see this statement:

> Note that this method only works with file paths (not, for example,
>   string representations of URLs).

The implementation of stringByAppendingPathComponent is "fixing" what it perceives as a badly formed file path.

You should either be using NSURLs or stringByAppendingString.

Answer (score 0):

Method `stringByAppendingPathComponent` is supposed to be used with file paths and not with urls so my feeling is that method logic is considering `//` a mistake and fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert your link to NSURL, then you can use URLByAppendingPathComponent:

```
if let blaFooURL = NSURL(string:"http://blah/")?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("foo") {
     println(blaFooURL)  // "http://blah/foo"
}
```